# ¿Cómo usar un "comodin" en el nombre de una variable?

Tags: python

Quiero asignar un número a una variable dentro de una función a modo de comodin de manera similar a como se usa al recorrer un listado accediendo a su indice.

Este es el código que tengo actualmente, y me gustaría reemplazar la variable color1 por color* (o donde haya un 1) dentro de la función.

```
color0 = 'red'
color1 = 'green'
color2 = 'blue'

def _func(ev):
    itm['C1'].BackgroundColor = color1
    # color1
    # color1
    # y otras tantas referencias a color1
    #...      
dlg.On.C1.Clicked = _func
```

Mi intento ha sido este:

```
color0 = 'red'
color1 = 'green'
color2 = 'blue'

def selColor(n):
    itm['C' + n].BackgroundColor = color[n]
    # color[n]
    # color[n]
    # ...

def _func(ev):
    n = 1
    selColor(n)
dlg.On.C1.Clicked = _func
```

Comment: Hola Alberto. No está muy claro lo que pides. ¿Puedes explicar mejor y añadir ejemplos del funcionamiento y resultado esperado ? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Como comenta lois6b no queda muy claro lo que buscas, si pretendes hacer referencia a una u otra variable `color_` usando el número para diferenciarlas no es posible directamente, si que puedes usar `eval`,  por ejemplo esto asigna a `c` el valor de la variable `color1`: `c  = eval("color{}".format(1))` pero en principio, si no existe una buena razón, no es ni legible, ni seguro o como mínimo  discutible cuando lo normal es usar un diccionario o una lista para esto.....

Comment: @FJSevilla ah, busca algun tipo de reflexión en cuanto al nombre de variable?

Comment: No.sé si ahora se entiende mejor lo que busco...

Comment: Porque no usas una lista?

Comment: Lo lógico sería que esas variables globales `color1`, `color2` y `color3` fuesen una lista `color`, pero si por lo que sea no tienes posibilidad de cambiar eso, siempre puedes crear una lista a partir de ellas: `color=[color1, color2, color3]`

Comment: En el código completo obtengo los valores de esas variables desde un json que contiene un dict, pero he tenido que definirlas por una cuestión de una librería que estoy usando y tiene ciertas particularidades a la hora de trabajar con determinadas estructuras de datos. Lo que quizá pueda probar es crear una lista a partir de ellas, como bien dices. Voy a ver si me sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Usar una lista con las variables color1, color2, color3,... me sirve, excepto para seleccionar un item que funciona por ID, y cuyas variables son string.

He probado con esto, intentando seleccionar por index, pero me peta la aplicación cuando se ejecuta la función _func, en la condición store == 1

```
color = [color0, color1, color2, color3, color4, color5]
ids = ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']

def selColor(n,i):
  toollist = comp.GetToolList(True).values()
  tool = []
  if store == 0:
    for tool in toollist:
      tool.TileColor = color[n]
  elif store == 1:
    color[n] = color
    itm[ids[i]].BackgroundColor = color[n]


def _func(ev):
  n = 0
  i = n
  selColor(n,i)
dlg.On.c0.Clicked = _func
```

Comment: `color[n]=color` no tiene buena pinta, es la misma variable a ambos lados de la asignación...

Comment: Eso es cierto! voy a cambiar una de ellas. Gracias!

Comment: `color[n] = currentColor` ahora si, funciona perfectamente!